# office communicator API for java

Tags: java, office-communicator

I need to contact the microsoft office communicator from a java application(without javascript). I require to get the contact id and ping them back through communicator.Is there is any Jars for doing this.
Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 3):

There is no specific java API for office communicator.

If your application is a client and you are well aware of accessing COM objects (Specific to windows) there is an API called [Jacob](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jacob-project) through which you can access communicator client COM objects to do your task

COM Reference API for Communicator http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lync/bb758755(v=office.12).aspx

If your application is a server then you can this [web services](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/ucmawcf/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=3845)  to connect to the OCS server.